# How to extract temperature value from HESTA Smart Band

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing a web app to connect to a bluetooth low energy thermometer. It's a HESTA Smart Band.

I can already connect and read its value. The problem is that I don't have any clue to extract its value into a temperature value.

Here are some BLE data that I got from the device.

> - 68 9F 06 00 5D 19 48 00 93 14 72 16
> - 68 9F 06 00 68 1B 48 00 93 14 7F 16
> - 68 9F 06 00 C1 1C 48 01 93 14 DA 16
> - 68 9F 06 00 56 11 48 01 93 14 64 16
> - 68 9F 06 00 6C 14 4C 01 6C 14 5A 16
> - 68 9F 06 00 DB 18 4C 00 65 15 C6 16

Obviously, Byte[5],[6],[9],[10] may present the temperatures. If I simply convert Byte[5], [6] to decimal, the results are as follow.

> - 195D => 25.93
> - 1B68 => 27.104
> - 1CC1 => 28.193
> - 1156 => 17.86
> - 146C => 20.108
> - 18DB => 24.219

But I'm not sure about that. Why Bytes[9],[10] also contain temperature values? And how about the other Bytes?

---

Edit:

I used bluetooth debugger and this is what I got:

> 0000fff0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Unknown Service

> Unknown Characteristics UUID: 0000fff1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb HANDLE: 11

> Properties: Value: (0x) 689F060050144C0150142216

--

> 0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Battery Service

> Battery Level UUID: 00002a19-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb HANDLE: 15

> Properties: Value: (0x) 00

As you can see, it can detect Battery Service and battery characteristic (0x2a19), but not the characteristic 0xfff1 which (I think) contains temperature value.

Comment: I used bluetooth debugger and this is what I got:

>0000fff0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Unknown Service
>Unknown Characteristics
>UUID: 0000fff1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
>HANDLE: 11
>Properties: 
>Value: (0x)  689F060050144C0150142216 

>0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Battery Service
>Battery Level
>UUID: 00002a19-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
>HANDLE: 15
>Properties: 
>Value: (0x) 00

As you can see, it can detect Battery Service and battery characteristic (0x2a19), but not the characteristic 0xfff1 which (I think) contains temperature value.

Comment: Unless the temperature of the device was changing quickly it seems unlikely those bytes are the temperature. Also as @ukBaz suggests, you should show the data messages corresponding to displayed values.

Comment: @ukBaz, barny
That's the reason why I'm asking this question. The "smart" band has no display screen to show the measured values. So I can't compare the calculated values with actual values.

Comment: @ukBaz I'm developing an app to get data from it for further processing. Actually, I received the device from the customer and they said that the manufacturer didn't public any official documentation.

Comment: @ukBaz No, this one. https://hesta-healthcare.com/smartband/
It's in Japanese...

Comment: Useful link, thanks. I see they are using a Bluetooth gateway to collect the data and not an app. There is every chance that the value is being sent encrypted or at least obfuscated. I probably can't help any more.

Comment: @ukBaz Thanks for your devoted help anyway. I could use the router's API to get the data but not understand its structure/encryption. I had make some experiments to check my assumption about Byte[5], [6] and it seemed to be correct. Byte[9], [10] change after each connection.